# Using dpkg --set-selections

Tags: 10.04, dpkg

I used the following commands to lock my Samba installation from upgrading.

```
echo samba hold | dpkg --set-selections
echo samba install | dpkg --set-selections
```

My question is simple.  How do I reverse this so that `apt-get upgrade samba` will work again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first command you listed places a package on hold

```
echo samba hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

The second command releases the package from hold

```
echo samba install | dpkg --set-selections
```

From [man dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html)

> --set-selections
>
> Set  package  selections  using  file read from stdin. This file should be in the format ’ ’, where state is  one of  install,  hold,  deinstall or purge. Blank lines and comment lines beginning with ’#’ are also permitted.

See also http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/67

Comment: So using the two together like that has essentially no effect then?  Everywhere I've seen that reference suggests that it will prevent Samba from updating.  This is incorrect?

Comment: The two have opposite effects, you use them in conjunction , the first for a hold and the second to remove the hold. Not sure what you have been reading, look at the man page and link I gave you.

Comment: The last like to article doesn't load properly (it's blank).